# Datagridview Checkbox C

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I have 10 records in my table let it be `X` and loaded the same in datagridview with checkbox, now I will select any of them so it will be reflected in another table let it be `Y`, Now what I need is when I show the records from `X` and if the same record is in `Y` it should be in checked mode other than that should have the possibility to select the check.

```
              if (CustomId == GridId)
                    {
                        if ((bool)this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value == true)
                        chk.Checked = true;

                    }
```

Comment: What your are trying to say?

Comment: Well @ Srinivasan, the user is trying to say that there are two table x and y, and the records is displayed to a Gridview with checkbox, and when user click on checkbox then that perticular records will get synced/added in table y, so when next time the grid is displayed all the synced record will persist checked value in their respective checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

After the DataGridView populated with the content of Table 'X', you can call function lets say

```
CheckSyncedRecordInTableX(String recordFromX)
```

In this function you can then traverse through each row in the Grid and then check if record is exist in the Table 'Y' or not

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewX.Rows)
{   
  //Check whether record exits in Table 'Y' or not.                         
  if(CheckSyncedRecordInTableX(ifValuerow.Cell[1].Value))
    {
      // Set checkbox to 'checked'

    }
}
```

Handle the checkbox checked event for each record in the GridView and update the value for record in Table 'Y' accordingly.